# how to use multerS3 to upload files to a private bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, multer

I have an S3 bucket where I have blocked all public access so that files can only be uploaded/downloaded from it via the root AWS credentials. I have tested functionality to download objects with `s3.getObject()`, which works successfully. I now want to be able to upload files to the bucket using `multer` and `multerS3`, which I am having trouble with.

In my code I have the following lines which should in theory give the required permissions to upload files:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: *secret key here*,
    accessKeyId: *public key here*,
    region: 'ap-southeast-2'
})
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'bucketname',
        acl: 'public-read',
        metadata: function (request, object, callback) {
            callback();
        },
        key: function (request, object, callback) {
            callback()
        },
    })
});
```

However, when I try to upload objects with this configuration I get an access denied error. Would anyone know why this is, even when the `s3.getObject()` function seems to work?